# How to move only particular item using drag and drop JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I don't want to move all the item to the div. I wants to move only specific item form one div to another

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #sortable1, #sortable2 {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 142px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">StoreID</li>    // I want to move only this STOREID li element to another UL
  <li class="ui-state-default">ItemLookupCode</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">ExtendedCost</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Quantity</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Price</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">

</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

I want to move only the first element of UL **StoreID** to another UL nor all the elements. How to achieve it.

Thanks

Comment: so you means, only storeId will be moved to another ul, not others right ?

Comment: @rahul_m yes. I have another `#sortable3` id, there it has to allow to drop only `ExtendedCost,Quantity,Price` from `#sortable1` not anyother.

Comment: @mohamedhafil your request is sort of weird. Why make list1 sortable if you only want to drag 1 item? Or do you mean list 1 and 2 should both be sortable, but only `StoreID` can be moved over to list 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is best done using `update` or `receive` callbacks. The key is: `ui.sender.sortable("cancel");` This will revert the change.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/4f5yh3pa/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default acceptable">StoreID</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">ItemLookupCode</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">ExtendedCost</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Quantity</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Price</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.connectedSortable {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 142px;
  min-height: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#sortable1 {
  background: #fff;
}

#sortable2 {
  background: #999;
}

.connectedSortable li {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(".connectedSortable").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    update: function(e, ui) {
      if ($(e.target).attr("id") == "sortable2") {
        if (ui.item.hasClass("acceptable")) {
          console.log($(this).attr("id") + " accepted item: ", ui.item);
        } else {
          console.log($(this).attr("id") + " rejected item: ", ui.item);
          ui.sender.sortable("cancel");
        }
      }
    }
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

You can animate this if you want to make it look more like draggable.

Comment: How to save and retreive from DB this order ?

Comment: @vignesh.D look at https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize and https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray to convert the list into data that can be sent to the DB via script. You will then need another script that gathers the data and can be reach like an API.